# How can I deduce that Fourier series of $f$ converges to $f$ in L^2([-L,L])

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

The question said:

Let $L > 0$ and for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ we take $$g_{n}(x) = e^{in \pi x/L},$$
We also define the Fourier coefficients of a function $f \in L^{1}([-L,L])$ to be $$c_{n}(f) = \frac{1}{2L} \int_{-L}^{L} f(x)\overline{g_{n}(x)}dx = <f,g_{n}>$$
The Fourier ..... I have solved all the questions in this question (with the help of many people) except letter (g)[image] I do not know how I will deduce from all the questions before (g) the answer of (g) I do not know exactly which letter before (g) will help me deduce (g), could anyone explain this for me?

Comment: Hint: Prove that the Fourier series weakly converges by looking at the scalar products with $g_n(x)$. Then, if you have weak convergence plus convergence of norms, you get strong convergence.

Comment: @Luke  but the question letter(c) said deduce, which means that I have to use the previous questions that I solved, which previous questions will I use in your hint?

Comment: @Luke sorry I mean letter(g)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

g follows from f using the following:
\begin{align}
      \|f\|_{L^2}^2&=\left\|\left(f-\sum_{n=-N}^{N}\hat{f}(n)e^{inx}\right)+\sum_{n=-N}^{N}\hat{f}(n)e^{inx}\right\|_{L^2}^2 \\
   &= \left\|f-\sum_{n=-N}^{N}\hat{f}(n)e^{inx}\right\|_{L^2}^2+\sum_{n=-N}^{N}|\hat{f}(n)|^2
\end{align}

Comment: From where did you get the last equality?Minkoviski?

Comment: @Intuition : Orthogonality. First, $\left(f-\sum_{n=-N}^{N}\hat{f}(n)e^{inx}\right)\perp e^{ikx}$ for $-N \le k \le N$, and $\|\sum_{n=-N}^{N}\hat{f}(n)e^{inx}\|^2 = \sum_{n=-N}^{N}|\hat{f}(n)|^2$.

Comment: Pythagorean theorem then Parseval`s identity, right?

Comment: @Intuition : Yes, and the Parseval is a finite Parseval.